# Correct method of sending a variable from a html form to a php function via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, post

I'm coding a voting system for multiple uploads; each uploaded image is in a foreach statement with a form attached to each, with three buttons to vote up, down or none, each associated with an INT in my mysql database.

I got it to work by submitting the form data straight to the PHP function that 'UPDATE's the database. To avoid a page refresh, I attach ajax. I got the ajax to send the two variables needed for the PHP function to update the correct "image" row and INT in the db.

**Question:** The ajax function works, but the PHP function doesn't seem to update.

SUSPECTED PROBLEM: I'm pretty sure it's the way I'm defining the variables in ajax that I want to pass, I was trying to grab the ID of the "image" it's handling, but I don't know how to translate this data to the PHP function so that it UPDATE's correctly.

Here's the form, javascript, and php:

```
// IMAGE, and rest of foreach above this, and ending after form
// This form only shows one button, there are three, each 
// I'll treat the same once I get one to work
<form action="feed.php" method="post" id="vote_form_1">

// If js isn't turned on in broswer, I keep this 
// hidden input, to send unique ID
<input type="hidden" name ="input_id" 
class="input_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>

<input type="submit" name="post_answer1" onclick="sayHi(event);"
class="answer_L" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
value="<?php echo $row['post_answerL']; ?>"/>

</form>
// end of foreach

//AJAX
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayHi(e) {
var input_id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
var post_answer1 = $("input[name='post_answer1']");
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'feed.php', //name of this file
        data:input_id,post_answer1,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result)
                {
                alert ('It worked congrats');
                }
    });
e.preventDefault();
</script>

// PHP VOTE UPDATE FUNCTION
<?php>
if(isset($_POST['post_answer1'],$_POST['input_id'])){
                $current_id = $_POST['input_id'];
                $vote_1 = "UPDATE decision_post set " . 
                   "post_answer1=post_answer1+1 WHERE id = '".$current_id."' ";
                $run_vote1 = mysqli_query($conn2, $vote_1); 
                if($run_vote1){ echo 'Success'; }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've trimmed down many of the irrelevancies in your question, in the future a question like this should be broken down to about 10 lines of code, see http://sscce.org for more info.  Pasting 100 lines of javascript, php and ajax code and then asking how can I get thingA to fromulate ThingB may generate positive and immediate results for you, but then you leave an artifact for future visitors to this page who have to wade through tons of complexity, and get bogged down and frustrated because 99% of it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll keep that in mind if I post a question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
var post_answer1 = $("input[name='post_answer1']").val();
```

Comment: This appears to have solved it, I appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple answer, just serialize all your form data!

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.post('feed.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'll try this! user6196179 found a mistake I made, but this seems like a better method generally. Thank you!

Comment: For shure, if you have more than 5 input, its better to user serialize [Jquery Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for more infos!